# androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag error in ContextCompat.registerReceiver [Broadcast receiver]

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver, android-13

```
       val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
                requireActivity(),
                smsBroadcastReceiver,
                intentFilter,
                ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
            )
        }else {
            requireActivity().registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
        }
```

Above is my code. I am trying to resolve a crash occuring on Android 14 devices. This is related to Google's policy change regarding broadcast receivers.

In my code,
Android Studio shows an error on RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED line and displays a prompt saying

> Must be one or more of:
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS,
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED,
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED

. Although I have already used RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED from androidx.core.content.ContextCompat, the error just doesn't go away.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to fix this?

Also, here is the crash message from firebase console:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
> org.samagra.missionPrerna: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or
> RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being
> registered exclusively for system broadcasts

I tried using Context as well as ContextCompat classes. My target and compile versions are 34.
Gradle has androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0 and 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' which are the latest versions. Still RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag shows an error.

Comment: Is anyone available to answer?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out lint was showing it as an erroneous code by underlining it in red but when I run the code on my device, it worked fine and the crash went away.